# How to create Android tabs like this (screenshot)?

Tags: android

Any idea how to implement tabs like these (the one on top with home image, star, etc)

[image: Tabs on top]

Comment: Also, in theory Stack Overflow isn't your personal research assistant, but in this case where all it takes is a single Google search, then it just might be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using tabs in an [action bar on Ice Cream Sandwich](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/ActionBarTabs.html).

Or [ActionBarSherlock tabs](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/TabNavigation.java) for a full on backward compatibility.

Comment: Those tab are not in the action bar.

Comment: On small devices, tabs in action bars appears on a second line.

Answer (score 3):

Those are so-called "swipey tabs", probably on top of a `ViewPager`. [`ViewPagerIndicator`](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) has an implementation of such tabs.

Comment: There is also a backward compat support for this : http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136). The solution there is to use the `setDividerDrawable(...)` method of the [TabWidget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabWidget.html) class. Then you can define the looks of the tabs with XML.

Comment: Not exactly the same but it can do.

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to use the same tabs-pager like on the android market app (aka google play) , you can get the android support library from the sdk manager and see their sample on ".../extras/android/support/samples/Support4Demos" .
there , find the fragment example called "tabs and pager" . i think you will like it ... :)