# is there an OnTabsChanged type of code

Tags: android, tabs

what I need is when I click on a tab I need to run through some code, is there anyway I could do this?

Comment: Do you have some code to show, there are plenty of tabs implementations these days :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439232/how-to-create-android-tabs-like-this-screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
getTabHost().setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

  @Override
  public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        //YOUR CODE
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use TabHost.OnTabChangeListener for that matter.