# How to Create tabs like Twitter or Instagram to work on all Android platforms > 2.2

Tags: android, tabs, compatibility

I've read some articles here
[How to create Android tabs like this (screenshot)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439232/how-to-create-android-tabs-like-this-screenshot)

later on in comments there is sherlock lib, that brings 4.0 look to devices having Android 2.2.

My problem is, I'm trying to make "ugly" :) old look to work on new devices.

Something like on image:

[image]

So I'd like to have Tabs, no Action bar, just 5 boxes with images and text that is preferably from string, as it need to be localized.

So, I'm using , and within tablayout.xml I do set title (from string),
and programatically I add image to certain tab from my resources.

```
th.setup();
    TabSpec specs = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
    //specs.setContent(new Intent(this,MyAppTab.class));
    specs.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    specs.setIndicator(getResources().getString(R.string.tab_myapp_title), getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab1_active));
```

What happens now, is that on my Android 2.2. phone, it looks ugly but with image, sort of what I'd like to have, and on wife's 4.0 I see fancy new tabs with text only.

How do I add tab image to work in all Android versions?

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom View as a Tab Indicator with [this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabSpec.html#setIndicator%28android.view.View%29).

1. Inflate the custom View

   - `View yourView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_tab_indicator, null);`
2. Populate it

   - `((ImageView) yourView.findViewById(R.id.tab_indicator_icon)).setBitmapRessource(...)`
   - `((TextView) yourView.findViewById(R.id.tab_indicator_title)).setText(...)`
3. call `tabSpec.setIndicator(yourView);`